# Nuxt component data not fetched

Tags: nuxt.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <button @click="showMe">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Index',

  async fetch ({ $axios }) {
    const result = await $axios.$get('https://api.sampleapis.com/beers/ale')
    console.log(result) // show arr that length 100.
    this.arr = result
  },

  data: () => ({
    arr: []
  }),

  methods: {
    showMe() {
      console.log(this.arr) // show arr that length 0.
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The [example on the official website](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching) is the same way.

But my `this.arr` is not updated.

What should I do to solve this problem?

This really drives me crazy.

why? Why the hell?

My Nuxt version is 2.15.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch(context)` only works on pages and is a [deprecated](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#the-fetch-hook) syntax:

> Before Nuxt 2.12, there was a different fetch hook that only worked
> for page components and didn't have access to the component
> instance. If your fetch() accepts a context argument, it will be
> treated like a legacy fetch hook. This functionality is deprecated,
> and should be replaced with either asyncData or an anonymous
> middleware

Instead you should use it like this:

```
    async fetch () {
     const result = await this.$axios.$get('https://api.sampleapis.com/beers/ale')
     console.log(result) // show arr that length 100.
     this.arr = result
   }
```